# Remove all images in a table, based on string containing a word on a href tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a flexigrid table 
and inside of it there are some href links with an image

I have two types of hrefs

```
<a href="add/11111111111111111111112" class=" crud-action" title="ADD R"><img src="http://www.gmurgente.es/imagenes/portada/google+.png" alt="ADD R" /></a>
```

and

```
<a href="remove" class=" crud-action" title="ADD R"><img src="http://www.gmurgente.es/imagenes/portada/google+.png" alt="ADD R" /></a>
```

I want to remove all images when they happen to have the remove word on the href, like:  `<a href="remove"`

I have tried the following

```js
$("#main-table-box").clone().find("img").remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flexigrid" style='width: 100%;' data-unique-hash="cab9e34d6d41015d6dfa951860ce4bf2">
  <div id="hidden-operations" class="hidden-operations"></div>
  <div class="mDiv">
    <div class="ftitle">&nbsp;</div>
    <div title="" class="ptogtitle"> <span></span>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div id='main-table-box' class="main-table-box">
    <div class="tDiv">


    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='clear'></div>
</div>
<div id='ajax_list' class="ajax_list">
  <div class="bDiv">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" id="flex1">
      <thead>
        <tr class='hDiv'>
          <th width='40%'>
            <div class="text-left field-sorting " rel='number'>Number</div>
          </th>
          <th width='40%'>
            <div class="text-left field-sorting " rel='number_2'>Number2</div>
          </th>
          <th align="left" abbr="tools" axis="col1" class="" width='20%'>
            <div class="text-right">Actions</div>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td width='40%' class=''>
            <div class='text-left'>12111212</div>
          </td>
          <td width='40%' class=''>
            <div class='text-left'>2323232332</div>
          </td>
          <td align="left" width='20%'>
            <div class='tools'>
              <a href="add/2323232332" class=" crud-action" title="ADD R">
                <img src="http://www.gmurgente.es/imagenes/portada/google+.png" alt="ADD R" />
              </a>
              <div class='clear'></div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="erow">
          <td width='40%' class=''>
            <div class='text-left'>12234132141444334343</div>
          </td>
          <td width='40%' class=''>
            <div class='text-left'>&nbsp;</div>
          </td>
          <td align="left" width='20%'>
            <div class='tools'>

              <a href="remove" class=" crud-action" title="ADD R">
                <img src="http://www.gmurgente.es/imagenes/portada/google+.png" alt="ADD R" />
              </a>
              <div class='clear'></div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width='40%' class=''>
            <div class='text-left'>21111111116789979</div>
          </td>
          <td width='40%' class=''>
            <div class='text-left'>11111111111111111111112</div>
          </td>
          <td align="left" width='20%'>
            <div class='tools'>

              <a href="add/11111111111111111111112" class=" crud-action" title="ADD R">
                <img src="http://www.gmurgente.es/imagenes/portada/google+.png" alt="ADD R" />
              </a>
              <div class='clear'></div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="erow">
          <td width='40%' class=''>
            <div class='text-left'>834845734</div>
          </td>
          <td width='40%' class=''>
            <div class='text-left'>834845734</div>
          </td>
          <td align="left" width='20%'>
            <div class='tools'>

              <a href="add/834845734" class=" crud-action" title="ADD R">
                <img src="http://www.gmurgente.es/imagenes/portada/google+.png" alt="ADD R" />
              </a>
              <div class='clear'></div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

## How to get a result like ?

[image]

Comment: You want to remove the image after clicking on the corresponding href?

Comment: Not at all, I want to remove all images that has remove on `href="remove"` I do not know how to delete all iimages on table on document start.... Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove elements by selecting them, and using the `.remove()` jQuery function ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)).

Something like the code below, where I select on the content of the `href` attribute:

```
$('a[href="remove"]').remove()
```

---

**EDIT: See snippet, works perfectly**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flexigrid" style='width: 100%;' data-unique-hash="cab9e34d6d41015d6dfa951860ce4bf2">
  <div id="hidden-operations" class="hidden-operations"></div>
  <div class="mDiv">
    <div class="ftitle">&nbsp;</div>
    <div title="" class="ptogtitle"> <span></span>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div id='main-table-box' class="main-table-box">
    <div class="tDiv">


    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='clear'></div>
</div>
<div id='ajax_list' class="ajax_list">
  <div class="bDiv">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" id="flex1">
      <thead>
        <tr class='hDiv'>
          <th width='40%'>
            <div class="text-left field-sorting " rel='number'>Number</div>
          </th>
          <th width='40%'>
            <div class="text-left field-sorting " rel='number_2'>Number2</div>
          </th>
          <th align="left" abbr="tools" axis="col1" class="" width='20%'>
            <div class="text-right">Actions</div>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td width='40%' class=''>
            <div class='text-left'>12111212</div>
          </td>
          <td width='40%' class=''>
            <div class='text-left'>2323232332</div>
          </td>
          <td align="left" width='20%'>
            <div class='tools'>
              <a href="add/2323232332" class=" crud-action" title="ADD R">
                <img src="http://www.gmurgente.es/imagenes/portada/google+.png" alt="ADD R" />
              </a>
              <div class='clear'></div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="erow">
          <td width='40%' class=''>
            <div class='text-left'>12234132141444334343</div>
          </td>
          <td width='40%' class=''>
            <div class='text-left'>&nbsp;</div>
          </td>
          <td align="left" width='20%'>
            <div class='tools'>

              <a href="remove" class=" crud-action" title="ADD R">
                <img src="http://www.gmurgente.es/imagenes/portada/google+.png" alt="ADD R" />
              </a>
              <div class='clear'></div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width='40%' class=''>
            <div class='text-left'>21111111116789979</div>
          </td>
          <td width='40%' class=''>
            <div class='text-left'>11111111111111111111112</div>
          </td>
          <td align="left" width='20%'>
            <div class='tools'>

              <a href="add/11111111111111111111112" class=" crud-action" title="ADD R">
                <img src="http://www.gmurgente.es/imagenes/portada/google+.png" alt="ADD R" />
              </a>
              <div class='clear'></div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="erow">
          <td width='40%' class=''>
            <div class='text-left'>834845734</div>
          </td>
          <td width='40%' class=''>
            <div class='text-left'>834845734</div>
          </td>
          <td align="left" width='20%'>
            <div class='tools'>

              <a href="add/834845734" class=" crud-action" title="ADD R">
                <img src="http://www.gmurgente.es/imagenes/portada/google+.png" alt="ADD R" />
              </a>
              <div class='clear'></div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<script>$(function () { $('a[href="remove"]').remove(); } ); </script>
```

Comment: I added script `$(document).ready(function(){    $('a[href="remove"]').remove();});`  but image is still showing, How to remove image too?

Answer (score 1):

An elegant ECMAScript 5 solution would be the following three-liner:

```js
[].slice.call(flex1.getElementsByTagName("a"), 0).
   filter(function(a) { return a.getAttribute("href") == "remove" }).
   forEach(function(a) { a.removeChild(a.children[0]) });
```

```html
<div class="flexigrid" style='width: 100%;' data-unique-hash="cab9e34d6d41015d6dfa951860ce4bf2">
  <div id="hidden-operations" class="hidden-operations"></div>
  <div class="mDiv">
    <div class="ftitle">&nbsp;</div>
    <div title="" class="ptogtitle"> <span></span>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div id='main-table-box' class="main-table-box">
    <div class="tDiv">


    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='clear'></div>
</div>
<div id='ajax_list' class="ajax_list">
  <div class="bDiv">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" id="flex1">
      <thead>
        <tr class='hDiv'>
          <th width='40%'>
            <div class="text-left field-sorting " rel='number'>Number</div>
          </th>
          <th width='40%'>
            <div class="text-left field-sorting " rel='number_2'>Number2</div>
          </th>
          <th align="left" abbr="tools" axis="col1" class="" width='20%'>
            <div class="text-right">Actions</div>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td width='40%' class=''>
            <div class='text-left'>12111212</div>
          </td>
          <td width='40%' class=''>
            <div class='text-left'>2323232332</div>
          </td>
          <td align="left" width='20%'>
            <div class='tools'>
              <a href="add/2323232332" class=" crud-action" title="ADD R">
                <img src="http://www.gmurgente.es/imagenes/portada/google+.png" alt="ADD R" />
              </a>
              <div class='clear'></div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="erow">
          <td width='40%' class=''>
            <div class='text-left'>12234132141444334343</div>
          </td>
          <td width='40%' class=''>
            <div class='text-left'>&nbsp;</div>
          </td>
          <td align="left" width='20%'>
            <div class='tools'>

              <a href="remove" class=" crud-action" title="ADD R">
                <img src="http://www.gmurgente.es/imagenes/portada/google+.png" alt="ADD R" />
              </a>
              <div class='clear'></div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width='40%' class=''>
            <div class='text-left'>21111111116789979</div>
          </td>
          <td width='40%' class=''>
            <div class='text-left'>11111111111111111111112</div>
          </td>
          <td align="left" width='20%'>
            <div class='tools'>

              <a href="add/11111111111111111111112" class=" crud-action" title="ADD R">
                <img src="http://www.gmurgente.es/imagenes/portada/google+.png" alt="ADD R" />
              </a>
              <div class='clear'></div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="erow">
          <td width='40%' class=''>
            <div class='text-left'>834845734</div>
          </td>
          <td width='40%' class=''>
            <div class='text-left'>834845734</div>
          </td>
          <td align="left" width='20%'>
            <div class='tools'>

              <a href="add/834845734" class=" crud-action" title="ADD R">
                <img src="http://www.gmurgente.es/imagenes/portada/google+.png" alt="ADD R" />
              </a>
              <div class='clear'></div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Make sure to include [an ECMAScript 5 polyfill](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim) to add backwards compatibility with [ECMAScript 3-only browsers](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/), if that's important to you.

Answer (score 0):

This will work, with plain javascript:

---

```js
var table = document.getElementById('flex1');
var a = table.getElementsByTagName('a');console.log(a);
for (var i= 0;i<a.length;i++) {
    var b = a[i].getAttribute('href');
    if (b == 'remove')
    {

           
var row = a[i].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;  
row.deleteCell(2);

    }}
    }}
```

```html
<div class="flexigrid" style='width: 100%;' data-unique-hash="cab9e34d6d41015d6dfa951860ce4bf2">
  <div id="hidden-operations" class="hidden-operations"></div>
  <div class="mDiv">
    <div class="ftitle">&nbsp;</div>
    <div title="" class="ptogtitle"> <span></span>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div id='main-table-box' class="main-table-box">
    <div class="tDiv">


    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='clear'></div>
</div>
<div id='ajax_list' class="ajax_list">
  <div class="bDiv">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" id="flex1">
      <thead>
        <tr class='hDiv'>
          <th width='40%'>
            <div class="text-left field-sorting " rel='number'>Number</div>
          </th>
          <th width='40%'>
            <div class="text-left field-sorting " rel='number_2'>Number2</div>
          </th>
          <th align="left" abbr="tools" axis="col1" class="" width='20%'>
            <div class="text-right">Actions</div>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td width='40%' class=''>
            <div class='text-left'>12111212</div>
          </td>
          <td width='40%' class=''>
            <div class='text-left'>2323232332</div>
          </td>
          <td align="left" width='20%'>
            <div class='tools'>
              <a href="add/2323232332" class=" crud-action" title="ADD R">
                <img src="http://www.gmurgente.es/imagenes/portada/google+.png" alt="ADD R" />
              </a>
              <div class='clear'></div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="erow">
          <td width='40%' class=''>
            <div class='text-left'>12234132141444334343</div>
          </td>
          <td width='40%' class=''>
            <div class='text-left'>&nbsp;</div>
          </td>
          <td align="left" width='20%'>
            <div class='tools'>

              <a href="remove" class=" crud-action" title="ADD R">
                <img src="http://www.gmurgente.es/imagenes/portada/google+.png" alt="ADD R" />
              </a>
              <div class='clear'></div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width='40%' class=''>
            <div class='text-left'>21111111116789979</div>
          </td>
          <td width='40%' class=''>
            <div class='text-left'>11111111111111111111112</div>
          </td>
          <td align="left" width='20%'>
            <div class='tools'>

              <a href="add/11111111111111111111112" class=" crud-action" title="ADD R">
                <img src="http://www.gmurgente.es/imagenes/portada/google+.png" alt="ADD R" />
              </a>
              <div class='clear'></div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="erow">
          <td width='40%' class=''>
            <div class='text-left'>834845734</div>
          </td>
          <td width='40%' class=''>
            <div class='text-left'>834845734</div>
          </td>
          <td align="left" width='20%'>
            <div class='tools'>

              <a href="add/834845734" class=" crud-action" title="ADD R">
                <img src="http://www.gmurgente.es/imagenes/portada/google+.png" alt="ADD R" />
              </a>
              <div class='clear'></div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to remove only the image, not all the row?

Comment: Now it's only the image @cMinor

Comment: @baoo  Thanks, One more question: supposing I have several images inside that cell (2) and I want only to delete the one with `href="remove"`, How to do it?  As I understand it is deleting all contents inside cell... But how to be more specific and delete only image?